# Identifying if a user has selected an RTL language

Tags: 2010, development, localization

**Scenario**: Running SharePoint 2010 with the Hebrew language pack installed.  On a particular site, English is set as the default language, but Hebrew is available for users as an Alternative Language.

**Issue**: In C# on a custom project, how can I identify when a user has selected a right to left language as their alternative language?

The following all return false:

1. SPContext.Current.RegionalSettings.IsUIRightToLeft
2. SPContext.Current.RegionalSettings.IsRightToLeft
3. SPContext.Current.Web.RegionalSettings.IsUIRightToLeft
4. SPContext.Current.Web.RegionalSettings.IsRightToLeft

And these return null:

1. SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings.IsUIRightToLeft
2. SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings.IsRightToLeft

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify:  I need the best way to 1) identify if the default language is RTL -and- 2) identify if the selected alternative language is RTL.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for hours, then posting this question, and searching for a few minutes more, I found the answer at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/b3e6712e-cbc1-44c3-916c-6d9855f3070f

Basically here is what I did and it works:

```
if(SPRegionalSettings.IsRightToLeftLocale(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID))
```

Works perfectly.